# How to add an image & a system bar button item to a UISegmentedControl?

Tags: iphone, uibarbuttonitem, uisegmentedcontrol

I have an `UISegmentedControl` as the navigation bar's right bar button item. This is achieved by the following code...

```
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [ [UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Segment1",@"Segment2",nil]];

[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];  //Where segmentClicked is the method for segment click action

segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 90, 35);

UIBarButtonItem *rightBaritem = [ [UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentedControl];

[segmentedControl release];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBaritem;

[rightBaritem release];
```

The above code fine and it will show a segmented Control with two segments "*Segment1*" & "*Segment2*".

But I want to show an image instead of *Segment1* & a system bar button (Say `UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd`) instead of *Segment2*.

Image can be inserted in Segmented control by the code,

```
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [ [UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"<image_name.image_type>"],???????,nil]];
```

But i dont know how to include `UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd` in the place of ???????.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1):

This code may solve your problem.This solved my problem that I was facing at the same time.But don't think this is the accurate one.I got the desired which I need to display.This works fine with two buttons.

```
UISegmentedControl *doneButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Done"]];
        doneButton.momentary = YES; 
        doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(240, 7.0f, 70.0f, 30.0f);
        doneButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(Done:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [menustyle addSubview:doneButton];
        [doneButton release];

        doneButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Close"]];
        doneButton.momentary = YES; 
        doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 7.0f, 70.0f, 30.0f);
        doneButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(Krishna:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [menustyle addSubview:doneButton];
        [doneButton release];
```

Comment: We cannot add tab bar item in segment controller